# add alternating classes to existing jquery object

Tags: jquery

I know I can do the following:

```
$('#mytable').find('tr:odd').removeClass('even');
$('#mytable').find('tr:even').addClass('even');
```

What if I already have `$('#mytable').find('tr')`.  How do I most efficiently add alternating classes?

Comment: Rethink this just slightly, you don't need to add two classes, `even` and `odd`, you only need to add one.

Comment: @Adam  Of course, wasn't thinking.  The question still remains.  How do I add/remove one class to a existing object.

Comment: Milind gave a good answer below before my comment was posted, I thought I'd leave the glory to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` works with  a selector as argument as well as using a function as argument

```
var $rows = $('#mytable tr');//cache all rows
// do something to specific class of rows
$rows.filter('.even').doSomething().doSomethingElse()
```

For your specific case, you could do:

```
$(function() {
  var $rows = $('table tr'); //cache all rows
  // do something to specific class of rows
  $rows.removeClass('even').filter(':even').addClass('even')
})
```

Comment: So maybe `$rows.removeClass('even').filter('.even').addClass('even');`?

Comment: yes  ...no need to use function callback to do exactly that. BUT  if you remove the class first, there won't be any `even` to filter

Comment: Actually I think my comment won't work since I am filtering on `.even`, and the class is gone.  I need to filter on `:even`.  Same approach?

Comment: use `':even'` as filter selector then, in which case removing the class will work

Comment: or with class existing on all rows and css to see change  http://plnkr.co/edit/DrIjA6Lovx7HXtfV2WIs?p=preview

Comment: Hope you didn't mind me editing your answer.  Couldn't really select it with it not directly answering the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()` for filtering out the elements based on condition:

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).is(':odd')
}).removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
```

and

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').filter(function(){
  return $(this).is(':even')
}).removeClass('odd').addClass('even');
```

Comment: Thanks Milnd.  I think this will work.  Note I changed my original post, but your idea still applies.

Comment: So, maybe something like `var existingObj=$('#mytable').find('tr'); existingObj.removeClass('even').filter(function(){return $(this).is(':even')}).addClass('even');`